# From HTML send an event plus variable to JS function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to send a mouse event and a variable to a JS function from within my html code, I can send the event fine but the problem is sending the event AND a variable. I have included a stripped down version of what I am trying to do. The browser is Chrome. Can anyone offer some advice please?

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function mouseDown(e,w) {
var ctrlPressed=0;
var evt = navigator.appName=="Netscape" ? e:event;

ctrlPressed =evt.ctrlKey;
self.status="" +"ctrlKey=" +ctrlPressed 

    if (ctrlPressed) 
    alert ("Mouse clicked with Ctrl/n and the variable is " + w )
    return true;
}

</script>
<body>

<table border = "1" >
<tr> 
<td onmousedown="mouseDown(e,\"variable\")"> Link 1 </td>
<td> Link 2 </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: You just have a mismatch of quotation marks. Use either `<td onmousedown="mouseDown(e,'variable');">` or `<td onmousedown='mouseDown(e,"variable");'>`.

Comment: Thanks Kenny but that is not the problem, its just an error when typing this question. I assure you it is correct in my code but it does not work . cheers

Comment: If that's the real problem I'd have answered instead of commented :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use browser detection. Check whether an object exists instead.

```
var evt = navigator.appName=="Netscape" ? e:event; // wrong
var evt = e ? e : event;    // right
var evt = e || event;       // also right
```

---

Since the event is passed as the 1st argument, you could try

```
<td onmousedown="mouseDown(arguments[0], 'variable');"> Link 1 </td>
```

(I have only tested this on Safari, not guarantee to work on other browsers.)

Comment: If you use `onmousedown="mouseDown(event, 'variable')"`, it'll work in IE and other browsers without any further fixes. This is because the first argument is defined to be called `event` on browsers that support event arguments, whereas on IE the same reference to `event` means the global `window.event`.

Comment: @kennytm when i tried to send event for my function by defining it like  var evt = e || event i got an error e is not defined.